# Selecting row from table

Tags: java, javafx

I have some problem when trying to get the first column value of selected row in table view. I populate my table data dynamically:

```
 private TableView<Category> viewCategory = new TableView<>();

public List<Category> populateCategoryTable() {
    List ll = new LinkedList();

    try {
        db.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM sm_category";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        // Call readRequest to get the result
        rs = db.readRequest(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String ID = rs.getString("categoryID");
            String name = rs.getString("categoryName");
            String desc = rs.getString("categoryDescription");
            Category row = new Category();
            row.setid(ID);
            row.setname(name);
            row.setdesc(desc);
            ll.add(row);
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error SQL!!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return ll;
}

public class Category {

private SimpleStringProperty ID;
private SimpleStringProperty name;
private SimpleStringProperty desc;

public void setid(String value) {
    IDProperty().set(value);
}

public String getid() {
    return IDProperty().get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty IDProperty() {
    if (ID == null) {
        ID = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "ID");
    }
    return ID;
}

public void setname(String value) {
    nameProperty().set(value);
}

public String getname() {
    return nameProperty().get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
    if (name == null) {
        name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    }
    return name;
}

public void setdesc(String value) {
    descProperty().set(value);
}

public String getdesc() {
    return descProperty().get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty descProperty() {
    if (desc == null) {
        desc = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "desc");
    }
    return desc;
}
}
```

And when the row is selected, I perform this on my table view:

```
viewCategory.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        // this method will be called whenever user selected row
        @override
        TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = viewCategory.getSelectionModel();
        ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
        TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
        int row = tablePosition.getRow(); // yields the row that the currently selected cell is in
    }
);
```

However, I got error message:

```
<anonymous shopManagement.boundary.RetrieveProductUI$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method changed(ObservableValue,Object,Object) in ChangeListener
```

and I have no idea why. Anybody can help?

**Updated Portion**

```
viewCategory.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    viewCategory.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE); // just in case you didnt already set the selection model to multiple selection.
    viewCategory.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TablePosition>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends TablePosition> change) {
            TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = viewCategory.getSelectionModel();
            ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
            TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
            int row = tablePosition.getRow(); // yields the row that the currently selected cell is in
            System.out.println(row);
        }
    });
```

I managed to display the data but I just can't get the selected row. It gives me an error message which is:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Answer (score 1):

YourChangeListener is not complete. you have an @override annotation but you didn't overide any method. Your changeListener need to be like that

```
    t.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String s2) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
t.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String s2) {
                 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                 int pos = table.getSelectedRow();
                 String value = (String) model.getValueAt(pos, 0); //current row, first column
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean putting inside the change listener?

Comment: I'll edit my answer with the complete code. EDIT: My code inside the `changed (...)` method returns you the value in the first column at the selected row.

Comment: There's whole bunch of error after adding these codes. no suitable method found for addListener(<anonymous ChangeListener<String>>)
    method ObservableValue.addListener(ChangeListener<? super RetrieveProductUI.Category>) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous ChangeListener<String>> cannot be converted to ChangeListener<? super RetrieveProductUI.Category> by method invocation conversion)
    method Observable.addListener(InvalidationListener) is not applicable

Comment: Also, I don't have getModel() and getSelectedRow() for table

Comment: Try removing the `listener` and putting my 3 lines of code into a button and see if errors still appear.

Comment: which listener you mean? Also how should I amend it? Because I am designing my app using scene builder

Comment: I mean this method: `t.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(...)`. Remove it and copy - paste `DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                 int pos = table.getSelectedRow();
                 String value = (String) model.getValueAt(pos, 0); //current row, first column` in a button event to check if errors still appear.

Comment: I hope you modified `table` with your current table name.

Comment: public void changedTable(ActionEvent event){
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) viewCategory.getModel();
                 int pos = viewCategory.getSelectedRow();
                 String value = (String) model.getValueAt(pos, 0); //current row, first column
    }

Comment: That's what I did but the error is still there and I wonder why because I imported the defaultTableModel already

Comment: Why aren't you using a normal `JTable` ?

Comment: Because javaFX does not support jTable. I have a complete code for jTable. I even tried to modify the code using javaFX but no luck

Comment: I noticed just now that it is JavaFX. Try look at this question and see if you find the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512755/how-to-set-and-get-the-cell-value-of-javafx-table-like-swing-jtable

Comment: But where do I call the setValue method?

Comment: You have to call it if you want insert a value in your table.

Comment: I am afraid that I am not inserting value into table. I am getting the  first column index of selected row

Comment: I know. Read that question and try to understand what does the code do. I think it does what you're looking for.

Comment: It's setting something to the row and column passed in. And I have no idea on how to modify it since I am getting the row. Would you mind to show me?

Comment: Are you able to get the desired row?

Comment: I only managed to retrieve the data from database and display them in table. As for the selected row part, nope.

Comment: Have you looked at this documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html

Comment: See my updated portion. I modified my code but I got index out of bound exception

Comment: at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
 at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:208)
 at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel$6.get(TableView.java:1757)
 at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel$6.get(TableView.java:1755)
 at shopManagement.boundary.RetrieveProductUI$1.onChanged(RetrieveProductUI.java:101)

Comment: Don't post the stack trace, just debug and check what doesn't work.